# What is the daily limit for the number of coins won with social interactions?

Tags: miitomo

There are several ways to win coins in Miitomo, but my question is only about the following possibilities :

- Answering a question (awards you 15 coins).
- Listening to a friend answer (awards you 5 coins).
- Commenting a friend answer (awards you 15 coins).

My question is, how many times can you win coins for each one of those on a daily basis ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you answer a question, you can gain 15 coins up to five times a day, so you can get a total of 75 coins.

The same applies for commenting a friend's answer : you will obtain 15 coins up to five times a day, for a total of 75 coins.

Listening to a friend's answer will award you with 5 coins up to ten times a day, so you can obtain 50 coins this way.

In total, you can obtain 200 coins on a daily basis this way.